# Team Services permissions - how to prevent dashboard access but allow GIT/Code access

Tags: tfs

is it possible to allow access to Team Services GIT repo but not allow

We have a Project X which we want to allow a user to access teh GIT repo but not see workitems etc

i have created a Team within Project X which is currently just inheriting from "Contributors" - i would like to lock this Team down so that it only has permission to the GIT repo and nothing else

is this possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could restrict access to resources that you manage in VSTS by **setting the permission state to Deny** through a security group/team.

You could deny the builds /Release and so on...  For a comprehensive list of default groups and permissions, see [Permission reference for Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions).

For restricting users to see work items, you could deny the **View work items in this node** permission under an Area path:

> **View work items in this node**
>
> If you set the View work items in this node to Deny, the user will not
>   be able to see any work items in this area node. **A Deny will
>   override any implicit allow**, even for accounts that are members of
>   administrative groups such as Team Foundation Administrators.

More details please refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions#nbspnbspnbsparea-path-object-level).

Comment: Ahh thats great i didnt know you could restrict to an Area